# Question about differential equation $y^{(4)}=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{(4)}=y$.

How many linearly independent bounded solutions exist?

If y is a bounded solution to $y^{(4)}=y$, and $y(0)=0$, find $y(2π)$.

Would the linearly independent bounded solution range just be $-∞<y<∞$?  I don't see any boundaries to this equation.

I integrated 4 times and got $y=\frac{y^5}{120}+C$.  I plugged in the initial value and got $\frac{(2π)^5}{120}$.  Is this right?  I have a feeling I did this problem incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: A function $f$ is called *bounded* if there is a constant $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ for all $x$.

Comment: Check your formula, to see that it is not a solution of the differential equation.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

We get $m^4 - 1 = 0 \rightarrow (m-1)(m+1)(m^2+1) = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2,3,4} = \pm 1, \pm i$

So, from these four roots, we have:

$$y(x) = c_1 e^{-x} + c_2e^x + c_3 \cos x + c_4 \sin x$$

- Now, how many linearly independent solutions are there?
- How do you determine if they are bounded?

Comment: Very nice hint, and right to the point! +1